# Get next row inside while loop in php

Tags: php

Please check my code and table. I need nex row "days" and starttime in else condition.

eg: If a user access a webpage on Friday after endtime. I need to show next day and start time in `echo "we are here for you again saturday from 9:00`

**Table**

```
id  days    starttime   endtime
1   Mon     10:00   18:00
2   Tue     10:00   18:00
3   Wed     10:00   18:00
4   Thu     10:00   13:00
5   Fri     10:00   18:00
6   Sat     9:00    14:00
```

**Code**

```
<?php
    require_once('dbconnect.php');
    $today         = date("D M j G:i:s T Y");
    echo $today. '<br>';
    $explode       = explode(" ", $today);
    $explode_day   = $explode[0];
    $explode_time  = $explode[3];

    $select        = "SELECT id, days, starttime, endtime FROM daytime";
    $execute       = $mysqli->query($select);
    while($row = $execute->fetch_assoc()){
        $days          = $row["days"];
        $starttime     = $row["starttime"];
        $endtime       = $row["endtime"];
        if($days == $explode_day){
           if(strtotime($explode_time) < strtotime($endtime)){
               echo "we were here for you";
           }
           else{
               $j=1;
               while($j <= 6):
                   echo "we are here for you again". $days . "from". $starttime;
                   $j++;
               endwhile;
           }
        }
    }
```

Comment: How come you've tagged PHP 5.3 and 5.6?

Comment: for that you need to get `next id` in current while loop and when else condition arrives you need to again query to fetch day using `next id`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used below code for getting results. I don't know this code is a good way but for my purpose it works good.

```
<?php
    require_once('dbconnect.php');
    $today         = date("D M j G:i:s T Y"); //Thu Mar 10 15:11:48 CET 2016
    //$today         = date("Thu Mar 10 15:56:48 CET 2016");
    echo $today. '<br>';
    $explode       = explode(" ", $today);
    $explode_day   = $explode[0];
    $explode_time  = $explode[3];
    $select        = "SELECT id, days, starttime, endtime FROM daytime";
    $execute       = $mysqli->query($select);
    while($row = $execute->fetch_assoc()){
        $days          = $row["days"];
        $starttime     = $row["starttime"];
        $endtime       = $row["endtime"];
        if($days == $explode_day){
           if(strtotime($explode_time) < strtotime($endtime)){
               echo "we were here for you";
           }
           else{
               $nextID        = $row["id"];
               $selectMinId   = "SELECT MIN(id) FROM daytime WHERE id > '$nextID'";
               $minIDExecute  = $mysqli->query($selectMinId);
               $minIdRow      = $minIDExecute->fetch_assoc();
               if($minIdRow['MIN(id)'] == '') {
                   $selectId   = "SELECT MIN(id) FROM daytime WHERE id = '1'";
                   $minID      = $mysqli->query($selectId);
                   $minRow     = $minID->fetch_assoc();
                   $id         = $minRow['MIN(id)'];
               }
               else{
                   $id         = $minIdRow['MIN(id)'];
               }

               $select        = "SELECT id, days, starttime, endtime FROM daytime WHERE id ='$id'";
               $execute       = $mysqli->query($select);
               $row           = $execute->fetch_assoc();
               $days          = $row["days"];
               $starttime     = $row["starttime"];
               if($days == 'Mon'){
                   $weekday    = "Monday";
               }
               else if($days == 'Tue'){
                   $weekday    = "Tuesday";
               }
               else if($days == 'Wed'){
                   $weekday    = "Wednesday";
               }
               else if($days == 'Thu'){
                   $weekday    = "Thursday";
               }
               else if($days == 'Fri'){
                   $weekday    = "Friday";
               }
               else if($days == 'Sat'){
                   $weekday    = "Saturday";
               }
               echo "we are here for you again".' '.$weekday.' '."from".' '.$starttime;
           }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try

```
continue
```

See here : http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.continue.php

Comment: Thanks I didn't used this. I will try this